Closing the trickle-down question
So I voted to close the trickle-down question, here is why I think you should too and why I think we should not reopen it.


I had no problem with the original question.

I mostly enjoyed 1muflon1's answer because I honestly thought this was a pro-policy slogan and not something made up by critics, so I was surprised there are no people with pro-trickle-down theories.

However I already felt that the answer put too much weight on this semantic issue. Granted that "trickled-down economics" is not well-defined, but it is quite simple to elicit what OP is thinking of by asking for clarification, and even though the question is obviously by a layperson, there was little focus on explaining how a stimulus for wealthy people may benefit other people as well.

Then the other answers came. Most of these are imprecise if not factually wrong, a lot of them are very grievance driven and have little to say besides condemning lefties' use of imprecise language. And they get a ton of upvotes. (Reader's exercise: guess why.) Because of this the question is becoming less and less useful for future visitors.

Therefore I propose closing it and posting two seperate questions, one purely on the phrase trickle down, and one on the general workings of targeted stimulus policies. Ideally the OP would do this, but they seem to have cut their losses and left. (Not a good sign of health for a question.)

It would be nice to have some policy for these sort of 'hot' questions but perhaps it is impossible to have a good general policy on this. I probably would not mind if suspension of 'newbie voting' was possible when protecting a question.



An addendum to 4. and 6. I wrote that I am bothered by the number of upvotes on answers that I personally deem to be of poor quality. One could argue that I am against "democracy" or the "wisdom of the masses" and on a technical forum I definitely am!


Technically there is already on this site rule of one question per question but the rule was never applied by past mods, if there is community interest on starting to be strict on that rule that could be potential solution going forward. However, ideally higher rep users should police these and homework questions etc. we already made only 3 votes required.  2. If you think some answer is bad because it’s too opinionated you could invoke our FAQ on answers policy that requires backing up claims with references. If the answer is not edited per rules it will be deleted regardless of upvotes


PS; I disagree it was clear what OP means. For example, now you use the phrase “stimulus for rich” but fiscal stimulus is not necessarily supply side policy (which is according to the sources the most common usage of the derogatory label “trickle down economics”). IMO it’s good to point out to OP that there is no clear answer, when there is legitimate uncertainty. I don’t think I was being overly pedantic here.

I agree pointing that out was good and I didn't write that you were pedantic. Did you try to ask for clarification and did you try to expand your answer based on the OPs feedback?


I didn’t said you claimed I was pedantic. It was just a self description. 2. But OP’s feedback was inconsistent. Feedback I got from OP went as follows; he said (in my words) that it refers to something, which he thinks I acknowledged, and I should talk about how that something would work. But the problem is that even if I would pick  often mentioned meaning “supply-side policy” it’s incredibly broad. Also OP insisted that I should talk about some system but there isn’t any supply side system. Supply side is a 1/2 of every macro system (other half being demand side).


AS-AD is a system. AS itself is not. I also don’t think that people who use the term trickle down economics talk about shifts in AS curve within IS-LM AS-AD model. 3. I also encouraged OP to pick some specific policy. I don’t mind giving OP answer on top marginal tax rates, but then OP should say, ok how are top marginal tax rates supposed to affect general income. OP wanted to have his cake and eat it too, he wanted some specific description of system but was not willing to specify which meaning of the trickle down pejorative he is interested in. I think in my answer I tried to meet him

Half way with the second part of the answer, if he is unwilling to go the other half way or follow your good advice of posting separate question about high taxes or some concrete supply side policy (or at least a close family of particular supply side policies) then that’s his prerogative. You can bring horse to water but you can’t make it drink. If you think there should be canonical answer for impact of higher taxes on general welfare you can also post separate question.

Okay, you certainly do not owe them endless engagement. I still think that the other answers that the question attracts are of low quality, due to the lack of clarity in the question; the easiest solution IMO is to close the Q and copy/move your answer to a new one that is more precise.

Poorly defined (at least in the realm of economics) political jargon will always an unusually high amount of poor answers. Closing the question seems fine. My advice as usual is for a more narrowly defined question, but that's harder for laypeople to construct.
